# MapFish Print 3 - Multiple maps on a file

Tags: printing, mapfish

I'm using MapFish to print maps and i'm stuck on a problem : printing 2 maps on the same page of a PDF.

If i want to print one map i do that :

In Config.yaml :

```
[...]
attributes:
  map: !map
    maxDpi: 400
    width: 390
    height: 510
  title: !string {}
  [...]
processors:
- !reportBuilder # compile all reports in current directory
  directory: '.'
- !createScalebar {}
- !createMap
  inputMapper: {map: map}
  outputMapper: {mapSubReport: map}
  [...]
```

In my template i have something like :

```
[...]
<subreport>
    <reportElement x="0" y="40" width="390" height="510" uuid="fa145068-76a5-4834-98ed-ce65b1976b3d">
        <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
    </reportElement>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{map}]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
[...]
```

And the JSON i send :

```
"map": {
  "center": [
    148641,
    168747
  ],
  "scale": 1234,
  "layers": [...],
  "projection": "EPSG:31370",
  "dpi": "72"
}
```

That works perfectly.

So i tried to adapt to have 2 maps, one on the left one on the right :

In Config.yaml :

```
[...]
attributes:
  mapLeft: !map
    maxDpi: 400
    width: 390
    height: 510
  mapRight: !map
    maxDpi: 400
    width: 390
    height: 510
  title: !string {}
  [...]
processors:
- !reportBuilder # compile all reports in current directory
  directory: '.'
- !createScalebar {}
- !createMap
  inputMapper: {map: mapLeft}
  outputMapper: {mapSubReport: mapLeft}
- !createMap
  inputMapper: {map: mapRight}
  outputMapper: {mapSubReport: mapRight}
  [...]
```

In my template :

```
[...]
<subreport>
    <reportElement x="0" y="40" width="390" height="510" uuid="fa145068-76a5-4834-98ed-ce65b1976b3d">
        <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
    </reportElement>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{mapLeft}]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
<subreport>
    <reportElement x="400" y="40" width="390" height="510" uuid="fa145068-76a5-4834-98ed-ce65b1187d52">
        <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
    </reportElement>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{mapRight}]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
[...]
```

And the JSON  :

```
"mapLeft": {
  "center": [
    148641,
    168747
  ],
  "scale": 1234,
  "layers": [...],
  "projection": "EPSG:31370",
  "dpi": "72"
},
"mapRight": {
  "center": [
    148641,
    168747
  ],
  "scale": 1234,
  "layers": [...],
  "projection": "EPSG:31370",
  "dpi": "72"
}
```

That doesn't work at all. Mapfish gives errors when loading the config.

So i guess i did it wrong, but i don't know how to make it work.

Does anyone have a suggestion ? Or even better a solution ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you said what the error was.

Comment: Hi @JohnBarça  

Here is the error i've got when i try to generate a PDF : 
`code`
The OneOf choice: MapBounds was not satisfied.  One (and only one) of the following fields is required in the request data: org.mapfish.print.attribute.map.AreaOfInterest areaOfInterest, double[] bbox, double[] center

It looks like mapfish wants the map attribute to be named "map" and ignores my leftMap and rightMap attributes.

Comment: Hi @sla please take a look here :) **https://github.com/mapfish/mapfish-print/tree/master/examples/src/test/resources/examples/datasource_multiple_maps**

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications (like the error message).